# mongoose connection works, mongo shell connection fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With `mongoose` I connect to the database using a url:

```
console.log(mongourl);
mongoose.connect(mongourl);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
  console.log('mongodb: connected');
});
```

And in the console:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/appname_development
mongodb: connected
```

But when I try to connect with the interactive prompt:

```
$ mongo mongodb://localhost:27017/appname_development
```

it blows up:

```
Wed Oct  2 14:43:57.390   Assertion failure _setName.size() src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h 211
0x10017116b 0x100135396 0x100068356 0x100129bab 0x10010f92f 0x10024b2fa 0x11b21ae06362 0x11b21ae0ce93 0x11b21ae400c9 0x11b21ae0c76e 
 0   mongo                               0x000000010017116b _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongo                               0x0000000100135396 _ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j + 310
 2   mongo                               0x0000000100068356 _ZN5mongo16ConnectionString5parseERKSsRSs + 1878
 3   mongo                               0x0000000100129bab _ZN5mongo17mongoConsExternalEPNS_7V8ScopeERKN2v89ArgumentsE + 187
 4   mongo                               0x000000010010f92f _ZN5mongo7V8Scope10v8CallbackERKN2v89ArgumentsE + 175
 5   mongo                               0x000000010024b2fa _ZN2v88internalL30Builtin_HandleApiCallConstructENS0_12_GLOBAL__N_116BuiltinArgumentsILNS0_21BuiltinExtraArgumentsE1EEEPNS0_7IsolateE + 618
 6   ???                                 0x000011b21ae06362 0x0 + 19456652764002
 7   ???                                 0x000011b21ae0ce93 0x0 + 19456652791443
 8   ???                                 0x000011b21ae400c9 0x0 + 19456653000905
 9   ???                                 0x000011b21ae0c76e 0x0 + 19456652789614
Wed Oct  2 14:43:57.393 JavaScript execution failed: Error: assertion src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h:211 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L114
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can duplicate your issue on my workstation.

If I drop the `mongodb://` and instead:

```
mongo localhost:27017/appname_development
```

It connects without exception. I'm not confident that using the `mongodb` prefix is supported for the command line console. The command line parsing is more simple and follows the very basic `Mongo` [class constructor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Mongo/#Mongo) (which is `host:port`).